# Gateway Time-out 504 "/web/models/TCM54/services/list.svc/getlist"

Tags: 2011, core-service, content-manager

Please let me explain the problem statement.

Problem statement: We are receiving Gateway (504) Time-out error while accessing one of out CMS folder via CMS explorer.
Error say's "Gateway Time-out "/web/models/TCM54/services/list.svc/getlist"

Analysis we did
1) We have noticed that this CMS folder contains more than 8000+ component.
2) We have also noticed that its a user specific issue i.e. if we open this folder via admin credentials (who have read/write permission for all 100+ publication) its works fine but with specific user credential (who have access to specific publication) it give 504 error, also this is something which occur suddenly as the user was working with same folder from months and haven't face the same.

Temporary solution:
1) As per our understanding when the user try to access this folder (having more than 8000+ components) in background Tridion hit core service "/web/models/TCM54/services/list.svc/getlist" which fetch data from its SOLR and cache it hence to clear the cache we have restarted the Tridion services/IIS  after 2-3 attempts its work fine.

Permanent Solution: ??? Can someone guide what is the workflow here and how we can find a permanent solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you on SDL Tridion 2011SP1HR2 version?, if yes following cumulative hotfix should improve the situation CM_2011.1.2.88651 (https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CM_2011.1.2.88651_tcm89-21633.zip) (login required)